# Vmware performance metrics into a a single CSV file for each VM

Tags: powershell, csv, powercli

I am trying to create a .csv file containing VmWare Performance metrics for several VMs.

The googlefoo'd examples I found generally separate each performance counter into individual .csv files which is not preferable. I would rather have one .csv per VM that contains all available Performance counters.

I would appreciate if you could please help me wrap my mind over how to get this done.
Here is what I have for now:

```
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore
Connect-ViServer my-vcenter

$vms = Get-Content list-of-vms.txt
$start = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

$vms | ForEach-Object {
    $metrics = (Get-VM $_ | Get-StatType)
    $output = @() #this is where i collect all the counters per line
    $hashtable = Get-Stat -Entity $_ -Stat $metrics -Start $start | Group-Object -Property TimeStamp

    For ($i=0; $i -lt $hashtable.Count; $i++) { # iterate through each timestamp
        $output = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{TimeStamp = $hashtable[$i].Name}
        For ($j=0; $j -lt $hashtable[$i].Group.Count; $j++) { # iterate through each counter in above timestamp
            $output| Add-Member -Name $hashtable[$i].Group[$j].MetricId -Type NoteProperty -Value $hashtable[$i].Group[$j].Value
        }
        $output | Export-Csv "$($_)_results.csv" -Append        
    }
}
```

The thinking process here is this:

For each VM, generate a hashtable with all available counters, grouped by time stamp.
Then, for each time stamp, extract each counters name, value type and add that as a LINE to a $output variable. Once all the recursive iterations are done, create an .csv file with the results.
.csv file's content would look like this as an example:

somevm_results.csv

```
TimeStamp, cpu.usage.average, mem.usage.average, etc

5/20/2020,50%,50%, etc
```

Comment: First thing that catches the eye: use `-lt` instead of `-le` in your for loops. Second, If you want one output csv for all VM's, write it after the last closing bracket `}` and use `Export-Csv` instead of `Out-File`

Comment: Thank you. It was sloppy on my part to put in the -le in there. Regarding the output, I am trying to create one .csv per VM. The problem is, every time I increment $output, it creates a new line. The intention is to get the "timestamp" into the first row of .csv from the first for loop, then append all the values from the second for loop to the same row. SO the end result will be one row with multiple columns: Timestamp, metrica, metricb, metricc, etc

Comment: I have updated the code to use PSObject to collect the data. So far, it just collects the very first TimeStamp entry disregarding the rest. Trying to figure out why

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get what i wanted. Below is the code that works for me.
if you have a suggestion on how to make it less of a mess of a code, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore

$vcenter = "my-vcenter"
Connect-ViServer $vcenter

<# use this if you want only specific counters
$metrics = "cpu.usage.average",
           "cpu.usagemhz.average",
           "mem.usage.average"
#>         

$vms = Get-VM (Get-Content -Path .\list.txt)
$start = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

$vms | ForEach-Object {
    $output = @()
    $metrics = ($_ | Get-StatType)
    $hashtable = Get-Stat -Entity $_ -Stat $metrics -Start $start | Group-Object -Property TimeStamp

    For ($i=0; $i -lt $hashtable.Count; $i++) { # iterate through each TimeStamp
        $output = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{TimeStamp = $hashtable[$i].Name}
        For ($j=0; $j -lt $hashtable[$i].Group.Count; $j++) { # iterate through each counter in above timestamp
                If ($hashtable[$i].Group[$j].Instance){ #check if a group has multiple instance names for the same counter
                    $counter_name = $($hashtable[$i].Group[$j].MetricId+"-"+$hashtable[$i].Group[$j].Instance+" ("+$hashtable[$i].Group[$j].Unit+")")
                } else {
                    $counter_name = $($hashtable[$i].Group[$j].MetricId+" ("+$hashtable[$i].Group[$j].Unit+")")
                }
                $counter_value = $hashtable[$i].Group[$j].Value
                $output| Add-Member -Name $counter_name -Type NoteProperty -Value $counter_value
        }
        $output | Export-Csv "$($_).csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation        
    }
}


Disconnect-VIServer $vcenter -Confirm:$false
```